# CSS Snap Scroll does not allow for jQuery scroll function to add or remove classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I have this implemented within my jquery file to detect if a certain `div` section is in `viewport`.

```
jQuery.fn.isInViewport = function($) {
    var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(this).outerHeight() / 2;
    var viewportTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHalf = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height() / 2;
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportHalf;
};

jQuery(window).on('load resize scroll', function($) {
    jQuery('.snappy').each(function() {
        var snapID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
        if (jQuery(this).isInViewport()) {
            jQuery('.sidenavitem').find("."+snapID).addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).addClass("in-view");       
        } else {
            jQuery('.sidenavitem').find("."+snapID).removeClass("active");
            jQuery(this).removeClass("in-view");
        }
    });
});
```

By itself, the `.on('load resize scroll')` function works and the active class gets added and removed but when I add this CSS style, the scroll function stops working and only works on the first one since there is `load` property

```
#main {
overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

.snappy {
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I am unsure if it's something within my CSS or my jQuery.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to where I have implemented this:
https://dev.staging.idgadvertising.com/genesistint/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly, the problem seems to be with the CSS properties for the `#main` element. The `max-height: 100vh` doesn't seem to play well with `overflow-y: scroll`.

By setting `max-height: 100vh` you are basically saying the `#main` element can only be as tall as the viewport height. And then by setting `overflow-y: scroll` you are explicitly instructing the browser to always show a vertical scrollbar, regardless of whether there is content overflowing or not.

This causes a conflict which results in `jQuery(window).on('load resize scroll', function($)` not triggering the callback function when the users scrolls the `window`.

Thus, the correct CSS could be either:

```css
#main {
  max-height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}
```

or (**I think this one is better**):

```css
#main {
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}
```

You don't need `overflow-y: scroll;` in there since the page seems to be always taller then viewport height, so the window's scrollbar is always displayed automatically.

---

**DIY DEBUGGING GUIDE:**

Firstly, I would optimize the JS code for better debugging. Create a separate function named `handleSideNav` just for handling the side navigation. After that, u could apply that function when the window loads, then apply the same function when somebody scrolls or resizes the window.

Notice the `console.log('Triggered event:', event);` line which is for debugging - now u can see which event was triggered, if any event was triggered at all. Delete this line after you are done testing.

```js
jQuery.fn.isInViewport = function($) {
    var elementTop = jQuery(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + jQuery(this).outerHeight() / 2;
    var viewportTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportHalf = viewportTop + jQuery(window).height() / 2;
    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportHalf;
};

function handleSideNav(event) {
    console.log('Triggered event:', event);
    jQuery('.snappy').each(function() {
          var snapID = jQuery(this).attr('id');
          if (jQuery(this).isInViewport()) {
              jQuery('.sidenavitem').find("."+snapID).addClass("active");
              jQuery(this).addClass("in-view");       
          } else {
              jQuery('.sidenavitem').find("."+snapID).removeClass("active");
              jQuery(this).removeClass("in-view");
          }
      });
}

jQuery(window).on('load', handleSideNav);

jQuery(window).on('resize scroll', handleSideNav);
```

Now u can refresh and scroll the page and see if any events are being triggered. With your original CSS, you can see in the browser console, that the `scroll` event won't trigger when you scroll the page. That indicates the even though u are scrolling, the browser doesn't register that as `window` scrolling, thus the problem might be with your CSS.

Comment: even though this does work, it still doesn't update the side navigation. I think it has to do with the CSS but I am not entirely sure, but if I was to remove the CSS properties, the side navigation works. If I add the css properties, the side navigation does not work. you can see the implementation on my question from the link.

Comment: @JasonAyala updated the answer for u